# i am using the active admin gem.but it comes error like this couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activeadmin

> source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'activeadmin'



# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by upgrading Active Admin to 0.6.1 / 0.6.2 or version-locking jquery-rails to < 3.

This has been documented [on Github](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2232). Basically: jquery-rails 3 separated jQuery UI out into its own gem, jquery-ui-rails.

Active Admin 0.6.0 and below optimistically [require jquery-rails >= 1](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/v0.6.0/activeadmin.gemspec#L22), while Active Admin 0.6.1 and above [blacklist jquery-rails 3](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/v0.6.1/activeadmin.gemspec#L26) in order to maintain backwards-compatibility with Rails 3.0.

Active Admin on master (1.0.0.pre) adds support for Rails 4 and drops support for Rails 3.0. There, Active Admin is able to [require jquery-ui-rails](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/3661d8958d02b82ea8c6796d4c052fedc894ba00/activeadmin.gemspec#L28).